# strncmp function does not stop checking at n characters?

Tags: c, cstring, strncmp

My program compares the 2 strings entirely and does not stop once n number of characters are reached? Why does this happen?

```
int strncompare (const char* mystring1,const char* mystring2, int number)
{
    int z;
    z = number - 1;
    while ((*mystring1==*mystring2) && (*mystring1 != '\0') && (*mystring2 != '\0'))
    {
        *mystring1++;
        *mystring2++;
        if ((*mystring1 == mystring1[z]) && (*mystring2 == mystring2[z])) 
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return (mystring1++ - mystring2++);
    }
```

Comment: Because you don't stop when you compare `number` characters? Also why are you doing `*mystring1++;`? You don't need the `*`. Please read a good C++ book before continuing.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but what do you think `*mystring1++;` and `*mystring2++;` do? I'm guessing it isn't what they actually do.

Comment: @SethCarnegie The `if ((*mystring1 == mystring1[z]) && (*mystring2 == mystring2[z]))` is supposed to check for that, but the check is wrong in its logic and its implementation.

Comment: Decompose! Decompose! Decompose! Yes, C++ allows you to write a single expression that does many magic things. But unless you understand what you do, why would you want this?

Comment: Oh.. your compare at the end..  First it is comparing the ponter, not the value, second the ++ after means it does the subtraction, then it does the increment.. It's not a good idea to have ++ on the same line as other things.. (unless you know how they work)

Comment: actually, the original code is sort of fun.. it would change the source.. the only way I see it ending is if the first characters are equal. eventually it'd roll the value back to zero.. and exit.. No?

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't stop when you've compared `number` characters.

There are several ways to do this, but I would recommend changing your loop condition to

```
while (*mystring1 && *mystring2 && *mystring1 == *mystring2 && number-- > 0)
```

Also remove

```
if ((*mystring1 == mystring1[z]) && (*mystring2 == mystring2[z])) 
{
    break;
}
```

Because, although it seems like that was your attempt at making it stop, it's coded wrong; you don't care if the *characters* are the same, you only care if you've compared `number` characters. Also you use `&&` which makes the condition even more restrictive than it already was.

Also change

```
*mystring1++;
*mystring2++;
```

To

```
mystring1++; // or better, ++mystring1
mystring2++; // or better, ++mystring2
```

The `*` dereferences the pointer but you're not doing anything with it so it's pointless (**pun intended**).

You also can remove the `++` from these:

```
return (mystring1++ - mystring2++);
```

So it would be

```
return mystring1 - mystring2;
```

However, that is undefined behaviour when the two pointers point to different arrays (which they probably always will). You need to be doing something else. What? I don't know because I don't know what your function should return.

Answer (score 0):

You have no condition in your function that examines `number`, or `z` that you derive from it.  What would make it stop?

Comment: `if ((*mystring1 == mystring1[z]) && (*mystring2 == mystring2[z]))` seems *intended* to stop at position `z` (`number`-1). Yes, I know that check is wrong, but I cannot find the words to explain it in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply decrement number and break when it reaches 0 assuming the loop hasn't broken by that point

Answer (score 0):

You should update z on each iteration and then check if it reaches zero, try adding this to your code:

```
if (z == 0)
    break;
else
    z -= 1;
```

Also, that check you have there is really faulty, if it worked it could stop at an unwanted time, for example on the strings "abcdec" and "xxcddc", where number = 6, it would stop at 3, because the characters at those indexes are the same as those on index 6.

Re-read your code very thoroughly and make sure you really understand it before taking any of these answers into account.

Answer (score 0):

This will walk until it finds a difference, or the end of the string.

```
while(n > 0) {
    if(*str1 != *str2 || *str1 == '\0'){
          return *str1 - *str2;; //they're different, or we've reached the end.
    }
    ++str1; //until you understand how ++ works it's a good idea to leave them on their own line. 
    ++str2;
    --n;
}
return 0;// I originally had *str1 - *str2 here, but what if n came in as zero..
```

the problem with the z compare is it's a moving target. 
think of [] as a + sign.. mystring1[z] could be represented like this  *(mystring1 + z)
That means the line above  ++mystring1;  (as it should be) is moving the pointer and thus moving where z is looking..

It might help to think of pointers as address on a street.. when you ++ you move up a house.. 
Say z = 1.. and the house that mystring1 points at is yours, and z is your neighbor.  add one to the house you're looking at, and mystring1 is now pointing at your neighbor, and z is pointing at his neighbor because z is still saying what your pointing at + 1.

Comment: you don't need to test both str's for 0.. if str2 is zero but str1 isn't, then the != would evaluate true.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all...I fixed the error...added another condition to the while loop.

```
int i;
i=0;
z = number - 1;

while((*mystring1==*mystring2) && (*mystring1 !='\0') && (*mystring2 !='\0') && (i<z))
```

and then incrementing i till it comes out of this loop.

Comment: also I changed the return to (*mystring1- *mystring2)